# Get Metadata from navigation property

Tags: c#

I want to know if there is better way to get navigation property metadata values with help of `ModelMetadataProviders` class?

Example of cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApp.Web.Service.OfficeService.PlayerDeposit>

<div id="pagedList">
    <table class="table Report tablesorter table-bordered table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="table-head sortTable">@Html.DisplayColumnNameFor(Model, m=> m.PaymentProvider.Name)
                </th>
                <th class="table-head sortTable">@Html.DisplayColumnNameFor(Model, m=> m.Country.CountryName)
                </th>
                <th class="table-head sortTable">@Html.DisplayColumnNameFor(Model, m=> m.NumberOfPlayers)
                </th>
                <th class="table-head sortTable">@Html.DisplayColumnNameFor(Model, m=> m.AmountDeposited)
                </th>
                <th class="table-head sortTable">@Html.DisplayColumnNameFor(Model, m=> m.Collected)
                </th>
                <th class="table-head sortTable">@Html.DisplayColumnNameFor(Model, m=> m.TransactionFee)
                </th>
                <th class="table-head sortTable">Balance
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
```

So for getting metadata names I had to create view helper with usage of `ModelMetadataProviders` class.

I couldn't find direct methodology to access navigation property names of supplied entity name, so I had to use old string manipulation (lil mess I know):

```
 public static IHtmlString DisplayColumnNameFor<TModel, TClass, TProperty>
    (this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, IEnumerable<TClass> model,
    Expression<Func<TClass, TProperty>> expression)
        {
            string entity = "";
            string name = "";
            ModelMetadata metadata = null;

            var expressionText = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
            name = helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(expressionText);

            if (name.Contains('.'))
            {
                int indexOfDot = name.IndexOf('.');

                entity = name.Substring(0, indexOfDot);
                name = name.Substring(indexOfDot + 1, name.Length - (indexOfDot + 1));

                Type classType = Type.GetType("WebApp.Web.Service.OfficeService." + entity);

                metadata =
                    ModelMetadataProviders
                        .Current
                        .GetMetadataForProperty(() => Activator.CreateInstance(classType), classType, name);
            }
            else
            {
                metadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForProperty(
                    () => Activator.CreateInstance<TClass>(), typeof(TClass), name);
            }

            return new MvcHtmlString(metadata.DisplayName);
        }
```

As you can see, since I don't really know if there is better way to directly access to navigation property from expression I firstly separated entity and name(I only count for one level deep navigation property) and then with help of reflection I got the class type so I could access entity metadata...

I tried old hack in html as instantiating the PlayerDeposit and then just use the model directly inside of html with `@Html.DisplayNameFor` but for some reason it didn't allow me(ambigious error): `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Carriers.FirstOrDefault().Name)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct thing to do here is use `ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression`.  It's important to note that for this application the `ViewDataDictionary` passed to `FromLambdaExpression` isn't going to be used for anything since we don't need to inspect the view data for values. We are getting the display name from the property itself.  That makes it relatively easy by allowing us to create a correctly typed `ViewDataDictionary` to use for the call.

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString DisplayColumnNameFor<TModel, TCollection, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,
        IEnumerable<TCollection> model,
        Expression<Func<TCollection, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        if (expression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");
        }

        var dictionary = new ViewDataDictionary<TCollection>();

        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, dictionary);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(metadata.DisplayName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it seems reasonable that you might want to have a different name for a model property when the item is used in a details view, I've created a similar extension that uses a custom attribute for column names.  You can find the above example (with a different name) and the additional method at https://github.com/tvanfosson/MvcExtensions/